# The HttpResponseMessage Doesn't work when the Content proprety is filled

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest

So im trying this HttpResponseMessage and it works fine as long as i dont put anything in the Content property. But i kinda need it now to return a json in the content of the message.

My code looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetMemberById()
{
    string id = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["id"];
    List<ClubMember> ls = KCBLL.Instance.FindMemberById(id);
    HttpResponseMessage MessageRetour = new HttpResponseMessage();
    if (ls.Count == 1)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string json = serializer.Serialize(ls.First());
        MessageRetour.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8);
        MessageRetour.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return MessageRetour;
    }
}
```

The interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "GetMemberById")]
HttpResponseMessage GetMemberById();
```

And finally the class

```
[DataContract]
public class ClubMember
{
    [DataMember]
    public long MemberId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MemberNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Also tried returning a Message Type and I still get a "Could not get any response"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but i figured it out.

The reason why it didn't work is because HttpContent in HttpResponseMessage is abstract (it also explains why the Message class didn't work well either). WCF's automatic converter with DataContractAttribute doesn't know what to do with abstract class.
I found 2 workaround for this problem.

1.Use JsonConvert from Newtonsoft to keep the Message type as your Return

- Serialize the object (Message or HttpResponseMessage)
- use UTF8Encoding.GetByte(yourjsonSerialized)
- New MemoryStream with byte array
- CreateStreamResponse(MemoryStream, "application/json") in WebOperationContext

2.Custom class wich contains your object by using custom Interfaces (or abstract class)and by using the KnowType attribute. Or by using the interface/abstract class of Message and HttpResponseMessage.

The cleaner way of doing it but it is the longest.